# Outlook Redemption gives error on initialisation

Tags: outlook-redemption

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim RDOSession As Redemption.RDOSession
  Set RDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")

End Sub
```

Gives the error:

Application-defined or Object-defined error
-2147221233

When the application loads. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means Redemption is not installed.

Did you install redemption.dll/redemtpion64.dll with regsvr32.exe?
What is the bitness of your app and Outlook?

Comment: That's what I thought but I downloaded and installed the developer version first. The app is 32 bit but the machine doesn't have Outlook installed, I wanted to connect to Exchange. Does Outlook have to be installed too?

Comment: The MAPI system must be installed, which means either Outlook or the standalone version of MAPI (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39045) must be installed.